# PHP strange situation in IF and Switch statment

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm encountering a very strange situation while working with `IF` and `Switch` statements in PHP. Can anyone explain why the `IF` condition below is coming true and not executing `ELSE` block. Same is the case with `Switch` statement, it is not executing the `default` block.

Thank you for your time :)

```
$error = TRUE;

if ($error == FALSE OR $error == 'stringValue') {
  echo 'Inside IF';
} else {
  echo 'Inside ELSE';
}

switch($error){
    case FALSE:
    case 'stringValue':
        echo 'Inside First';
        break;

    default:
        echo 'Inside Default';
        break;
}
```

Comment: `true == 'string'` Results in `true`, `true === 'string'` results in `false`

Comment: due to true == "somthing"  and specially for OR operator.

Comment: @devpro Thank you :)

Comment: always welcome (Khush amded)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened just because of this line:

```
if ($error == FALSE OR $error == 'stringValue') {
// your stuff
}
```

Here you define $error as true and using OR operator.

`$error == 'stringValue'` is also means something coming true.

**A basic example:**

```
$error = true;

if ($error == "somthing") {
  echo 'Inside IF';
} else {
  echo 'Inside ELSE';
}
```

It will always print **"Inside IF"** but why? just watch this example:

```
if (true == "somthing") {
  echo 'Inside IF';
} else {
  echo 'Inside ELSE';
}
```

both will be treated as same. try it.

Comment: So you could compare with `===` in an if else statement, but would that be also possible with switch case? Or does switch case always compare with `==` ?

Comment: @KhorneHoly why would you use a boolean in a switch ? And no according to the documentation: `Note that switch/case does loose comparision.`

Comment: @khorneHoly Thank you pal :)

Comment: @daan Thank you too :)

Comment: @Daan I'm just trying to understand this. I've asked myself a few times what the big difference between switch and if/else would be, this is quite a big difference, that's why I'm asking

Comment: in switch, yes it compare same like if else, according to PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$error = TRUE;

if($error === FALSE || $error === 'stringValue') {
 echo 'Inside IF';
} else {
 echo 'Inside ELSE';
}

switch($error){
case FALSE:
//case 'stringValue':
    echo 'Inside First';
    break;

default:
    echo 'Inside Default';
    break;
}

?>
```

you can do this thing also in your code -

just make **$error ='TRUE';** as a string , because it is boolean at this time  .

Comment: dont forget to appreciate by voting up.

Answer (score 1):

It is for the type. the == check equal after type juggling. But if you want to check same type you should have to use === . Which return true if both operators are same type. So you may use === instead of ==. 

DO like this-

```
$error = TRUE;

if ($error === FALSE OR $error === 'stringValue') {
  echo 'Inside IF';
} else {
  echo 'Inside ELSE';
}
```

It display Inside ELSE. 
For more information check it- 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, the == operator is not matching the type, but only value, so if 2 values with different types are compared PHP is trying to convert the one of the variables to type of the other one.

The same thing is applied to using switch. I test this option to cast $error to string type.

```
$error = TRUE;

if ($error == FALSE OR strval($error) == 'stringValue') {
  echo 'Inside IF;
} else {
  echo 'Inside ELSE';
}

switch(strval($error)){
    case FALSE:
    case 'stringValue':
    echo 'Inside First';
    break;

    case TRUE:
    echo 'Inside true'; break;
    default:
    echo 'Inside Default';
    break;
}
```

Output
   Inside ELSE Inside true